# Why do the contents in a Bootstrap grid float left? Is there a way to get the contents in a Bootstrap grid to be in the center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried using `text-align: center;`, but this does not change the text inside of the Bootstrap grid. Is the float-left the default setting or is there a way I can change it? My code looks something like this:

```
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-right: 20%; margin-left: 20%; text-align: center; font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace; background-color: white;   border-radius: 50px;">
        <h1 style="padding-top: 10px;">Code Example</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 "><a style="color: black;">Column 1</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a style="color: black;">Column 2</a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><a style="color: black;">Column 3</a></div>
        <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that `padding-left` can be used. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it is something at least.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Copy-paste the stylesheet  into your  before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.
''''''
if you are missing this link please add .I hope it will work.

Comment: You seem to have a great deal of typos. Could you rephrase that?